# Picasso image url lookup before load

Tags: android, picasso

So I'm currently investigating the possibility to replace a lot of custom image loading `AsyncTask`s in a project, with the Picasso library and it seems promising. However there is one issue that I'm not completely sure how to solve using Picasso.

In this case we are downloading Album Art for music tracks, however when our ListView is to be shown we only have the track ids. So first we have to lookup an Album Art URL based on the track id and then load it into an ImageView. Currently we have an `AsyncTask` where we in `doInBackground()` first lookup the image URL and then load a `Bitmap` from it, which is then pasted to `onPostExecute`.

Is there any way to make this pre-lookup using Picasso or will we have to wrap the Picasso call in a `AsyncTask` that first perform the lookup (and feels like it kinda defeats the purpose).

**Update: How it works now:**

```
private class AlbumArtTask extends AsyncTask<String, Bitmap, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
        final String id = strings[0];

        // This part is what I'm asking for, basically to be able to make an Async
        // lookup of the url that will later be used by Picasso
        final Uri uri = getAlbumArtUriFromTrackId(id);

        // Creating the Bitmap and return it to be used in an ImageView
        // This part is handled by Picasso
        return bitmap = createBitmapFromUri(uri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        // load image into ImageView
    }
}
```

**Update 2: Made up example of what I'm after**

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
    .load(new UriProvider() {         

        // Get the actual image URI here
        public Uri getImageUri() {
            return getAlbumArtUriFromTrackId(id);
        }

     })

      // And load it here
     .into(mImageView);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of lookup before loading?

Comment: Is it because you need the bitmap for other purposes? You can get it directly from the imageview afterwards if that's the case.

Comment: What does you mean by pre-lookup? You have to show placeholder from local storage or have to show pre-lookup image other that original from server..

Comment: Currently editing the question, but in short we are loading Album Art for tracks and when our ListView is to be shown we only have the track ids. So we first need to lookup an album art url based on a track id and then load that url into an ImageView.

Comment: So if no image is found you want to show a default image after lookup?

Comment: Hang on, I'm writing a code example of what I mean.

Comment: please check answer and let know what else.

Comment: Could you solve this issue? I am with the same problem

Comment: Afraid not :-/ had to put this on hold since it was more of an optimization than a blocking issue. I have a hunch that it could be solved by attaching a OkHttp interceptor and perform the lookup there, but I haven't tried it out yet.

Answer (score 1):

I had to solve the same problem for my app. I used OkHTTP interceptor to redirect the request.

This is my picassa declaration:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.interceptors().add(new PhotoInterceptor());
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
    .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(client))
    .build();
```

This is a basic implementation of the interceptor:

```
public class PhotoInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            Photo photo = gson.fromJson(response.body().charStream(), Photo.class);
            if (photo!=null) {
                request = request.newBuilder()
                    .url(photo.getPhoto_file_url())
                    .build();
                response = chain.proceed(request);
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: this just returns the png data for me, I can't see a way to get the image url?

Answer (score 0):

You have to load images from your *Album Art URL* using Piccaso while your listView is created.  Then on Detail screen of Track you have to call your actual image url to set it in imageview.

**Edited**

```
private class AlbumArtTask extends AsyncTask<String, Bitmap, Uri> {

        ImageView  mImageView;
        Context mContext;    
        public AlbumArtTask(Context context,ImageView imageView){
           this.mImageView=imageView;
           this.mContext=context;

        }

                @Override 
                protected Uri doInBackground(String... strings) {
                    final String id = strings[0];

                    // This part is what I'm asking for, basically to be able to make an Async 
                    // lookup of the url that will later be used by Picasso 
                    final Uri uri = getAlbumArtUriFromTrackId(id);

                    // Creating the Bitmap and return it to be used in an ImageView 
                    // This part is handled by Picasso 
                    return uri;
                } 

                @Override 
                protected void onPostExecute(Uri uri) {

                    // You have to pass imageview in constructor.
                    // load image into ImageView 
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(uri)/* And load it here*/.into(mImageView);
                } 
            }
```

Comment: Yeah but the problem with that solution (if I'm not mistaken) is that the `getAlbumArtUriFromTrackId(id)` call will be made on the UI thread which is  not possible since network calls are not allowed on the UI thread

Comment: What I'm after is to make the URL lookup on the same thread as Picasso is loading the image. The alternative would be to create an AsyncTask which then launches the Picasso.load(..) but I don't see that as a good solution.

Comment: Moving the `Picasso` call to `onPostExecute` results in images flickering/ending up in the wrong position while scrolling the ListView. That's one of the problems I want to resolve by changing to Picasso since it takes care of that kind of problem (at least when loading images normally)

Comment: Are you passing imageview from constructor to asyncTask or Have AsyncTask class inside your adapter class ?